# Python pandas return value from other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a file "specieslist.txt" which contain the following information:

```
Bacillus,genus
Borrelia,genus
Burkholderia,genus
Campylobacter,genus
```

Now, I want python to look for a variable in the first column (in this example "Campylobacter") and return the value of the second ("genus"). I wrote the following code

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

species_import = 'Campylobacter'
df = pd.read_csv('specieslist.txt', header=None, names = ['species', 'level'] )
input = df.loc[df['species'] == species_import]
print (input['level'])
```

However, my code return too much, while I am only want "genus"

```
3    genus
Name: level, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can select first value of Series by `iat`:

```
species_import = 'Campylobacter'
out = df.loc[df['species'] == species_import, 'level'].iat[0]
#alternative
#out = df.loc[df['species'] == species_import, 'level'].values[0]
print (out)
genus
```

Better solution working if no value matched and `empty Series` is returned - it return `no match`:

> @jpp comment
>   This solution is better only when you have a large series and the matched value is expected to be near the top

```
species_import = 'Campylobacter'
out = next(iter(df.loc[df['species'] == species_import, 'level']), 'no match')
print (out)
genus
```

EDIT:

Idea from comments, thanks @jpp:

```
def get_first_val(val):
    try:
        return df.loc[df['species'] == val, 'level'].iat[0]
    except IndexError:
        return 'no match'

print (get_first_val(species_import))
genus

print (get_first_val('aaa'))
no match
```

EDIT:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'species':['a'] * 10000 + ['b'], 'level':np.arange(10001)})

def get_first_val(val):
    try:
        return df.loc[df['species'] == val, 'level'].iat[0]
    except IndexError:
        return 'no match'


In [232]: %timeit next(iter(df.loc[df['species'] == 'a', 'level']), 'no match')
1.3 ms ± 33.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [233]: %timeit (get_first_val('a'))
1.1 ms ± 21 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)



In [235]: %timeit (get_first_val('b'))
1.48 ms ± 206 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [236]: %timeit next(iter(df.loc[df['species'] == 'b', 'level']), 'no match')
1.24 ms ± 10.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: To expand, the second solution is better only when you have a large series *and* the matched value is expected to be near the top. You can also use `try` / `except IndexError...` for the first solution in case of no match.

Comment: @jpp - I think here better not raise error, but I think you think faster, right?

Comment: If the value is near the bottom, or the series is small, I expect the `loc` solution to be faster. Because (I think) `__next__` calls via `iter` are expensive vs NumPy array access. Depends on data.

Comment: Works great. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @jpp - I am a bit confused, I try timings and output is similar, not sure if I understand you or some another problem. Please check timings.

Comment: @jezrael, OK, so I think I know what's happening. I misread your answers. Both your answers use Boolean indexing, i.e. O(*n*) complexity. But if you do an element-by-element check you can get a faster method if match is near the top. I've posted something as community-wiki.

Answer (score 3):

Performance of various methods, to demonstrate when it is useful to use `next(...)`.

```
n = 10**6
df = pd.DataFrame({'species': ['b']+['a']*n, 'level': np.arange(n+1)})

def get_first_val(val):
    try:
        return df.loc[df['species'] == val, 'level'].iat[0]
    except IndexError:
        return 'no match'

%timeit next(iter(df.loc[df['species'] == 'b', 'level']), 'no match')     # 123 ms per loop
%timeit get_first_val('b')                                                # 125 ms per loop
%timeit next(idx for idx, val in enumerate(df['species']) if val == 'b')  # 20.3 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

#### `get`

With `pandas.Series.get`, you can return either a scalar value if the `'species'` is unique or a `pandas.Series` if not unique.

```
f = df.set_index('species').level.get

f('Campylobacter')

'genus'
```

If not in the data, you can provide a default

```
f('X', 'Not In Data')

'Not In Data'
```

We could also use `dict.get` and only return scalars.  If not unique, this will return the last one.

```
f = dict(zip(df.species, df.level)).get
```

If you want to return the first one, you can do that a few ways

```
f = dict(zip(df.species[::-1], df.level[::-1])).get
```

Or

```
f = df.drop_duplicates('species').pipe(
    lambda d: dict(zip(d.species, d.level)).get
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Change the last line of your code to 
print(input['level'].values) 
# For Explanation refer below code

import csv
import pandas as pd

species_import = 'Campylobacter'
df = pd.read_csv('specieslist.txt', header=None, names = ['species', 'level'] )

input = df['species'] == species_import # return a pandas dataFrame

print(type(df[input])) # return a Pandas DataFrame

print(type(df[input]['level'])) # return a Pandas Series 

# To obtain the value from this Series.
print(df[input]['level'].values)  # return 'genus'
```